# Instantiate generic c# List when the reflected type itself is a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics, reflection

I have a reflected Type, which ends up being a `List<Type>`. So I have:

```
Type modelType = GetMyType();
```

So - `modelType` could be `List<ClassA>` or `List<ClassB>`, etc. depending on the situation.

How do I create this type, and then populate it?

I know I can do this:

```
var myList = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
```

But then how do I add items to it, which I would normally do with `myList.Add(new ClassA())` or `myList.Add(new ClassB())` knowing that I don't really know the `ClassA` or `ClassB` type - I just know that modelType is `List<ClassA>` - Is there some other way I should be instantiating it so that I can add items to it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This looks a lot like XY problem...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the XY problem? I get my object type from another method, which I then need to populate, based on what I get from that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this example, it uses the [Type.GetGenericArguments Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the lists inner type. Then proceed with reflection as usual.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type modelType = GetMyType();
        var myList = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);

        var listInnerType = modelType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var listInnerTypeObject = Activator.CreateInstance(listInnerType);

        var addMethod = modelType.GetMethod("Add");
        addMethod.Invoke(myList, new[] { listInnerTypeObject });
    }
    static Type GetMyType()
    {
        return typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType((new Random().Next(2) == 0) ? typeof(A) : typeof(B));
    }

class A { }
class B { }
```